# Zooming capabilities for Line Charts in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to allow or to add the capability to zoom in/out of a line chart in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) 2012, other than the use of Dundas Charts?

Comment: Hi @HassanMokdad unfortunately interactive zooming in SSRS is not possible due to limitations in the reporting services. How do you zoom in/out with Dundas chart? In my company we use [Nevron chart for SSRS](https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-overview.aspx) and we achieve zooming through parameters - e.g. filtering the chart axis range and etc.

Comment: Hi Ramzy, to be honest i still didn't try the Dundas charts, i took an alternative path and used HTML 5 charts, through normal asp.net web applications.

Comment: as long as this works for you is all good. Perhaps you might like to answer your question giving a bit more information how you've achieved this so if someone has a similar requirement can find a solution.